# jQuery UI & Admin (Calendar)

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-admin, jquery

Am I smoking crack or why wouldn't this work? :/ This all seems pretty straightforward:

```
function admin_head()
{

?>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/css/jquery-ui-1.8.9.custom.css"  />
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/js/jquery-ui-1.8.9.custom.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/js/theme-admin.js"></script>
<?php

}

add_action('admin_head', "admin_head");
```

And then in theme-admin.js ...

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($)
{   
    $("#datepicker").datepicker({
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true, dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy', showOn: 'button', buttonImage: plugin_path + '/images/icon-datepicker.png', buttonImageOnly: true});

});
```

Thank you for any insight you can provide :) Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Duh, if you're **image path is bust** and it's the only way it activates, it just won't load.

Answer (score 1):

You might also want to look at using [wp_enqueue_script](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script) and [wp_enqueue_style](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_style), rather than echoing those script & style tags.  Using these functions helps to eliminate duplicate scripts and styles, as well as introducing some dependency support.